# Core aspnet identity password validator based on the configuration

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

```
 public static IdentityBuilder AddCustomPasswordValidator<TUser>(this IdentityBuilder builder, PasswordValidateOptions options) where TUser : class
    {

        if (!options.EmailInPassword)
            builder.AddPasswordValidator<EmailInPasswordValidator>();
        if (!options.UserNameInPassword)
            builder.AddPasswordValidator<UserNameInPasswordValidator>();
        if (!options.LastPasswordsInPassword)
            builder.AddPasswordValidator<LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator>();      
        return builder ;

    }
```

in the above method, I can not pass arguments via prop or constructor to the IPasswordvalidator implementation.

for instance LastPasswordValidator, I want to configure based on the no. of password counts from the Options, but AddPasswordValidator doesn't take any data.

```
public class LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator:IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>
{



    private int LastPasswordsCount { get; set; }

    public LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator(IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher)
    {
        this.passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
    }
}
```

This is what I would like to

```
 builder.AddPasswordValidator<LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator>(options);
```

but the AddPasswordValidator has no overload.!!!

Comment: Have you tried injecting the options as a dependency into your validator constructor?

Comment: @Brad, did tried, however its same. I guess I will have to override IdentityBuilder.AddPasswordValidator method to accept Generic type with parameters in the constructor. I'm really not sure, because its the Identity base class.[ private PasswordValidateOptions PasswordValidateOptions { get; set; }
        public LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator(IOptions<PasswordValidateOptions> options)
        {
            this.PasswordValidateOptions = options.Value;
        }]

Comment: its more like,how to pass data along with the type!!

Comment: You can create your own overload for `AddPasswordValidator` because it's just an extension method.  Are you adding the options to your services in startup using `services.Configure<PasswordValidationOptions>()`?

Comment: @Brad, yes I'm adding the configuration. I have added multiple extension methods, but this one I don't know the implementation of AddPasswordValidator. Also I would like to pass the options data to LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startup Configure services.

Ioptions pattern made life easier, ++Core design pattern
no need to pass data via properties/Constructor when we need the data across application, Ioptions hold it for you

```
 services.Configure<PasswordValidateOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("PasswordValidateOptions"));
```

Implementation of IpasswordValidator

```
private PasswordValidateOptions PasswordValidateOptions { get; set; }
        public LastPasswordsInPasswordValidator(IOptions<PasswordValidateOptions> options)
        {
            this.PasswordValidateOptions = options.Value;
        }
```

Comment: So you implemented as my comments suggested that you said wasn't working.  Interesting.

Comment: @Brad, that suggestion was great, yes indeed did tried but wasn't worked because of some other dependency in the code as I was looking in the issue in a different perspective to resolve which made me shift focus. when I revisited the core Ioptions pattern then spotted and understood that I missed the basic point. but back on track. your suggestion did worked for me